# Generar key con keytool

Tags: android, cmd, keystore

Estoy generando una `key` y acceder a `keystore` para su conexión con `android goolgle` el problema es que nunca se genera, se queda en un bucle infinito de pedir datos, no importa cuantas veces llene el formulario, ponga `yes`, si es `consola PS`, `CMD`, o `modo administrador`, es el mismo tema, nunca cierra el bucle

```
keytool -genkey -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.store
```

> no importa si genere `.key` , `.store` o lo que sea, nunca sale del bucle

el cual serviria para generar

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

llevo dias tratando de generarlo, desde diferentes lugares, modos, etc, pero no sale del bucle, da igual si lleno todo o no lleno nada, no error, ni sale del bucle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No deberìas tener problema usando la utilerìa `Keytool`, pero actualmente lo recomendable es usar Android Studio, ve a `Build` - `Generate Signed Bundle / APK...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la opciòn `Create new...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquì puedes crear tu Keystore:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: despues de esperar media hora salió este error `error de herramienta de claves: java.lang.RuntimeException: Ha habido demasiados intentos, se ha cerrado el programa`

Comment: Probablemente no es Keytool, es algùn proceso que tiene problemas o no se esta ejecutando, te sugiero reinicies la pc y trates nuevamente.